# How can I insert the content of a combobox into the body of a word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm new here!

Someone can answer how to insert the text of an activeX combobox control into the body of the word document (using the click event or change event, for example)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Is the combobox also part of the documents?

Comment: Yes, the combobox is in the same word document

Comment: I have already add the items and now I want to "transfer" them to the body of the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could for example use `InsertAfter` to insert the selected value of the combobox at the end of the document.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

You can also use `InsertBefore`.

Comment: Thank you, I have just already find the same solution!